# Cannot boot ubuntu due to corrupt disk

Tags: boot, grub2, data-corruption

I am having a problem with my main hard disk which I normally boot to.

When I tried to switch on tonight and couldn't boot to ubuntu and was presented with `grub rescue` due to a bad sector.
I tried `insmod normal` but that wouldn't run with the same bad sector error.

So I booted from a usb and ran `fsck` on the drive, there were a few errors and I pressed **y** them all.

Tried to boot again and got to `grub rescue` again this time `insmod normal` cannot find files

> error: file '/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found.

So I went back to the usb boot and I ran 

`mkdir /mnt/hdd
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/hdd`

But there doesn't seem to be any files in there.

I checked the `disk` utility and its showing the disk as 86% full, so I'm hopefully my files are recoverable.

How do I get back up and running with my data?
My long term plan is to replace the disk, but I am worried about the state of the data and how I get it back.

If it makes a difference its Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: after mounting did you do `cd /mnt/hdd` followed by `ls` ?

Comment: Yes, nothing there